# Change background color link based on payment method in Woocommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Is there any way to change order view color link on admin page table, based on chosen payment method, currently I have 2 payment method: paypal and cash on delivery.

> `IF` payment method "Cash on delivery" `==>` change background color link red 
>   `ELSEIF` payment method "Paypal" `==>` change background color link green.

Here is an example:
[image: screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

*I know is a little bit late but maybe my anwser is helpfuly for someone else. I used Wordpress in version 4.9.8 and WooCommerce in version 3.4.4*

There is no direct way to change the order view link but with a little bit JavaScript and CSS it is possible to change to change the link.

## My idea:

I add an CSS class for every payment method as hidden field to the order column. Then I   detect the order view link with JavaScipt and add the CSS class to that link.

## Code:

### Plugin PHP File:

```
/**
 * Add payment method as hidden field
 */
function my_function_to_add_the_payment_method($column)
{
    // the hidden field is only added in the order column
    if($column == 'order_number' )
    {
        global $post, $the_order;

        // order data
        if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() !== $post->ID ) {
            $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        }

        // only continue if the order is not empty
        if ( empty( $the_order ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // the WooCommerce standard payment methods are:
        // bacs     => Direct bank transfer
        // cod      => Cash on delivery
        // paypal   => Paypal
        // cheque   => Check payments

        // add payment method as hidden field 
        // JavaScript can add the css class from the data attribute to the a.order-view link
        echo '<input type="hidden" class="my-hidden-payment-method" name="my-hidden-payment-method" data-class="css-'. esc_attr( $the_order->get_payment_method() ) .'" value="'. esc_attr( $the_order->get_payment_method() ) .'" />';

    }
}

/**
 * hook to add the payment method to the order
 */
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'my_function_to_add_the_payment_method');

/**
 * Add JavaScript and CSS
 */
function my_function_to_add_the_js_file($hook)
{
    if( is_admin() AND $hook == 'edit.php' AND $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' )
    {
        // add JavaScript file and CSS file only on the "WooCommerce order overview" page (WooCommerce -> Order)

        // JS
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_payment_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) ."/js/my-payment-script.js", array('jquery'), NULL, true );

        // CSS
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_payment_style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) ."/css/my-payment-style.css", array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    }
}

/**
 * hook to add the javascript and CSS file
 */
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function_to_add_the_js_file' );
```

### Javascipt "/js/my-payment-script.js":

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    // runs over every hidden field with the class "my-hidden-payment-method"
    $('.my-hidden-payment-method').each(function(i, obj) {

        var $element = $(this);

        // copy the css class form hidden field to the order-view link
        $element.siblings('a.order-view').addClass( $element.data('class') );

    });


})( jQuery );
```

### CSS "/css/my-payment-style.css":

```
.css-bacs, .css-cod, .css-paypal, .css-cheque
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.css-bacs {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.css-cod {
    background-color: red;
}

.css-paypal {
    background-color: green;
}

.css-cheque {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

## Result:

[image: WooCommerce order overview with coloured order links]